# Put array into DataFrame as single element

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Guys,

I have an dict like this :

```
dic = {}

dic['A'] = 1
dic['B'] = np.array([1,2,3])
dic['C'] = np.array([1,2,3,4])
dic['D'] = np.array([6,7])
```

Then I tried to put them into a DataFrame (also may insert more lines later, but the array length for each element may be variable), for some reasons, I want to keep them as a entire object for each columns, when print, it looks like:

```
A             B             C        D
1       [1,2,3]     [1,2,3,4]    [6,7]
......
[2,3]     [7,8]     [5,6,7,2]        4
```

When I am trying to do this by :

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)
```

I always get the error : ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Do I have anyway to keep the entire array as single element, however, some times I do have some single value as well ?

Comment: why do you require dict input is mediatory with problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you required input as the dictionary. but if you pass elements as numpy array it converts missing values with NaN.

```
pd.DataFrame([np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([6,7])],columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

Output:-

```
   A  B    C    D
0  1  2  3.0  NaN
1  1  2  3.0  4.0
2  6  7  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, np.array([2,3])],
                   "B":[np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([7,8])],
                   "C":[np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.array([5,6,7,2])],
                   "D":[np.array([6,7]), 4]})
```

So `df.to_dict()` returns

```
 {'A': {0: 1, 1: array([2, 3])},
 'B': {0: array([1, 2, 3]), 1: array([7, 8])},
 'C': {0: array([1, 2, 3, 4]), 1: array([5, 6, 7, 2])},
 'D': {0: array([6, 7]), 1: 4}}
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to save to file you should consider to use lists instead of numpy arrays and use `delimiter=';'`

Answer (score 0):

convert arrays to strings by if you want to maintain this shape.